# Count different days of the same month

Tags: php, mysql

I select specific rows from the MySQL database and get the following list:

```
2017-07-28
2017-07-28
2017-07-28
2017-07-28
2017-07-31
2017-07-31
2017-08-01
2017-08-01
2017-08-02
2017-08-02
2017-08-02
2017-08-03
2017-08-04
```

I would like to count how many days per month were different, in this case I would like to get the following result:

```
2017-07: 2 different days
2017-08: 4 different days
```

I tried to do this with the help of arrays but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m') AS year_month
      , COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(date_col)) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m');
```

How it works:

- first create group based on `year-month` part
- use aggreagate function `COUNT` to count occurences in each group
- `DISTINCT` to get only different values of day in month

Comment: I think he is new to mysql so explain to him what does group by mean here and why it's the required solution

Comment: I get NULL when running this query:
    $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m') AS year_month, COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date)) AS cnt FROM xxx GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m');";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $row) {}
    var_dump($row);

In MySQL dates are stored as timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (dt) VALUES
('2017-07-28'),
('2017-07-28'),
('2017-07-28'),
('2017-07-28'),
('2017-07-31'),
('2017-07-31'),
('2017-08-01'),
('2017-08-01'),
('2017-08-02'),
('2017-08-02'),
('2017-08-02'),
('2017-08-03'),
('2017-08-04');

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m') yearmonth, COUNT(DISTINCT dt) total FROM my_table GROUP BY yearmonth;
+-----------+-------+
| yearmonth | total |
+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07   |     2 |
| 2017-08   |     4 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen (slow day ;-) )